# Can I use Google's office as a coworking space?

Tags: offices, coworking

I realised today [Google has offices in Amsterdam](https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=google%20amsterdam%20office&*). It's in my favorite part of Amsterdam (Amsterdam Zuid, it's a very hi-tech part with tall skyscrapers). I am myself a software engineer working as a freelancer for companies around the world, so a change of environment would be good sometimes (especially a Google-like environment).

Can I sometimes drop by and work on my own stuff from there? I tried calling them using the number Google itself supplies (020 504 5100), but got nothing, only a voice machine asking me what kind of support do I need.

TLDR; Do Google offices have a guest area? Where people can work on their own stuff, hang out, eat, drink, whatever?

Comment: Sure thing, I did that by calling them up, but they seem to be unreachable (see my text).

Comment: It takes like 45m to get there.

Comment: I'm thinking someone may know.

Comment: If a random stranger called you and and said "Can I come over tomorrow, sit in your living room, use your wi-fi, help myself to your kitchen, and listen in to  your conversations?" would you be very receptive? Providing temporary working space is a business. Google is not in that business, so they're very unlikely to provide it for free. In the end  @Joe Strazzere 's comments are the only real answer. I'm just guessing that the answer is almost certainly "NO!".

Comment: I'll make it easy for you: No you can't. Source: My common sense.

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant you should make this an answer.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere he can also use an even cheaper resource: Common sense.

Comment: makes sense, but you guys don't have to dicks about it

Comment: Ok so they aren't answering your call, you don't want to ask them in person, you want *us* to somehow tell you the answer, and when we point out that you should ask them not us, we are "dicks"?

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to ask to know for sure. But nothing to stop you just going in and trying. If you don't ask no one can say no, and if there is an issue you can just apologise and leave.

When I started my first consulting business I didn't have an office and I lived an hours drive from my clients who were all in town. Transport was eating all my money so eventually I parked up at the local library every day and ran my business out of there for a couple of months until I had enough for an office. No one even noticed. Got some good reading in as well which was a bonus.

Answer (score 2):

If I were you - and disclaimer, I am not you - I would look at making a meetup group to handle this. Which would also look good on your CV.

You are correct that Google does - despite what some commenters on your question have snarked  - offer free campuses around the world. In London there is one, with a nice cafe, fast wifi and (aside from food) it is totally free. It is a very nice space and I work there often.

Joe has linked to the relevant section in the comments - it would appear such an offer is not in Amsterdam.

There are generally rentable co-working spaces that you should look into - I fear my Dutch is not adequate (it is non-existant, really) to give you pointers, but again in London it is not unheard-of for office space to be rentable and pretty affordable.